# Linux: How to save a image using ImageIO.write()?

Tags: java, linux, javax.imageio

I am writing a screen capture program on Linux using Java. How can I use `ImageIO.write()` like I used it on windows like:

```
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("c:/output.png"));
```

Comment: `System.exec("gnome-screenshot")`

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: The user's home  directory one gets with `System.getProperty("user.home");` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a screen capture *program*, then you probably want to use a FileChooser to allow the user to choose where to output the file.

Here's a simple example of how you could implement one:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = jfc.showSaveDialog();

if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File outputFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", outputFile);
}
```

This will also help to make your code fully cross-platform, instead of hard-coding platform-specific paths into the program.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux there is no "C:\" drive. Instead, your drive is mounted at a **mount point** (usually `/`). You could write to your home directory (equivalent of Win7's `C:\Users\yourusername\`) with either of these:

```
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("/home/yourusername/output.png"));
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("~/output.png"));
```

or to the temp folder (if you have permissions) with:

```
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("/tmp/output.png"));
```

You could also write to the current directory with a simple:

```
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("output.png"));
```

To find your drive's mount point, run `df -h` in a terminal to see all mounted drives.

Comment: but did same as u mention but i getting path not found error, i have given hard code path then also same exception is coming but if i giving desktop path it is saving ... what exaclty the problem in my case